# .exe as Windows Service error 1053, run as user and it works

Tags: asp.net-core, windows-services, signalr

I've an an .exe file (WebHost with signalR application) that, when ran as a user, is running fine. I wanted to turn it into a windows service with the following command, `sc.exe create myService start=auto DisplayName=MyCustomService binPath="D:\bla\bla\bla\MyCustomService.exe"` runs fine, the service is created. Then when I want to start the service, it reaches a timeout with an error 1053. However is I run manually `D:\bla\bla\bla\MyCustomService.exe`, it launches pretty quickly and without any error. Privileges are sufficient, there is no dependencies issue, I'm wondering what am I doing wrong here ? Is it related to the use of AspNetCore ? SignalR ? I doubt it...

EDIT : the .exe is a published version with -c Release

Comment: Just because you can install an executable as a service doesn't mean that it will work! Details here: https://www.coretechnologies.com/blog/windows-services/sc-service-fails-to-start/

Comment: Ok, but not only executing it directly works, but I explained that to avoid the commentary : "Have you created the service before ?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fix the issue, this is dumb but could not find the answer after hours of research (it was mentioned in @CoreTech comment) : the application was not defined as a windows service (even if it is a WebHostApp).

So in my program's Main method, I just added to the HostBuilder .UseWindowsService() (Thanks to a co-worker). And now, no problem.